# Using pyes, how do I let elasticsearch choose the index id?

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

Below is how I index:

```
   conn = ES(['127.0.0.1:9200'],bulk_size=bulk_count)
   conn.index(tj,data['index'],data['type'],str(uuid4()),bulk=True)
```

I am using uuid but would rather have ES choose the index id for performance reasons.  How do  implement that in pyes so ES will auto create the index id?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you do not set the id elasticsearch automatically generates one for the document. It will be UUID-1 and it is much better for performance reasons.

Proof links:
1. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html#_other
2. http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2014/05/choosing-fast-unique-identifier-uuid.html

So the best choose - is using Zero-padded sequential ids.